# Laravel Cashier auto send email on invoice / receipt

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

On Stripe document / Laravel cashier it says it can send email automatically after invoice was created. I tried to switch the settings related on that on Stripe's settings menu, but I am not receiving any email after I purchase or subscribe. Do I still need to manually code the email sending? ( I am thinking that it should be automatically sent after invoice was created )

Comment: I'm not sure how Laravel Cashier uses Stripe, so you probably should check with them / read up on their docs/code to figure out how they do things; if the 'invoice' they use is a Laravel object and not a Stripe Invoice, then the Stripe settings wouldn't work as you'd expect them to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts#automatically-send-receipts-when-using-billing), if you want Stripe to automatically send receipts, You have to set customer’s email parameter when creating a subscription and ensure that the option email customers for successful payments is enabled on [Stripe dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/emails)

```php
$user->newSubscription('default', 'monthly')
    ->create($paymentMethod, [
        'email' => $user->email, // <= customer’s email
    ]);
```

Please note that:

> Receipts for payments created using your **test API keys** are not sent
>   automatically. Instead, you can view or manually send a receipt using
>   the [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/payments).

---

But if you want to send receipts by Laravel instead, You can [define a new webhook event handler](https://laravel.com/docs/master/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks) and use [Stripe webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks):

1. Set up a new endpoint at [Stripe dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/webhooks) to `https://your-domain.com/stripe/webhooks`
2. List the URI as an exception in your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware or list the route outside of the `web` middleware group:

   ```
   protected $except = [
       'stripe/*',
   ];
   ```
3. Define a new `WebhookController` and add a `handleInvoicePaymentSucceeded` method to the controller to handle the `invoice.payment_succeeded` webhook:

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController as CashierController;
   use App\Notifications\InvoicePaid;

   class WebhookController extends CashierController
   {
       /**
        * Handle payment succeeds.
        *
        * @param  array $payload
        * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
        */
       protected function handleInvoicePaymentSucceeded(array $payload)
       {
           $invoice = $payload['data']['object'];
           $user = $this->getUserByStripeId($invoice['customer']);

           if ($user) {
               $user->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice));
           }

           return new Response('Webhook Handled', 200);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Define a route to your Cashier controller within your `routes/web.php` file. This will overwrite the default shipped route:

   ```
   Route::post('stripe/webhook', '\App\Http\Controllers\WebhookController@handleWebhook');
   ```
5. (Optional) You can manually set Stripe's webhook signatures for more security.

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks) form more info.

Comment: Thanks mate! Awesome clarification. thanks for pointing out that the "test API keys are not sent automatically", I was testing the wholeday haha